# Reloading resources loaded by getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, web-applications

Following best practices, I'm using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream` to load resources in a web application (like text files or xml files), instead of going through the file API.

However, this has the disadvantage that if the resource changes on disk, a following call to getResourceAsStream keeps returning the old version indefinitely.

I would like it to pick up the new version though. In my debugger I see there's a simple HashMap called resourceEntries in the classLoader. Using reflection I've been able to remove a specific entry and this seems to work.

This method is however fragile.

Is there a more standard way to do this?

Comment: what is the exact implementation of `ClassLoader` that holds that?

Comment: In this case it was a ``org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader`` in Tomcat 5. I haven't tried in newer Tomcat versions yet, but I just tried it in JBoss and it doesn't work there (as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to kschneid's answer which might work for Tomcat indeed, I wanted to add that for JBoss AS 5+ it already seems to work without needing any special tricks.

Caching of resources is probably class loader specific. The JBoss AS one either doesn't cache or is smart enough to see that the resource on disk has changed.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ClassLoader ctxLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resURL = ctxLoader.getResource(resName);
URLConnection resConn = resURL.openConnection();
resConn.setUseCaches(false);
InputStream resIn = resConn.getInputStream();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally solved this problem by change the jar file name, every time i change the resource content, i change a new name with current timestamp