# Re-Reading internal files in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, directory

I am reading a file using libgdx function Gdx.files.internal. The file is placed on the Android's folder assets. And once the application is launched on the desktop I change the file and re-read it. But it does not work. I mean, the application reads the older file although I just changed it. Here's the code chunk

```
public Scenario getScenario(String scenarioName)
{
    FileHandle f = Gdx.files.internal(scenarioName);
    return new Scenario(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f.read())));
}
```

Does anybody know why Gdx.files.internal is still reading the old file? Of course once I stop the application and relaunch it, the new file is read. What's wrong here?

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wait.. You write it and THEN read it? Wouldnt it be easier to just use the data you wrote to it instead of reading and possibly parsing the file? Or am I completely misunderstanding?

Comment: ... So smart,;) I didnt explain wholly. I am writing the file by hand and using parsers. Then reloading from application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gdx Internal files are read only. That is why when you read it again you get the same data again.
If you want a file that you can read AND write to  you'll need to use either Local or External.
The file types are explained in more detail [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling#File_%28Storage%29_Types).

If you want to supply the initial version in the Android assets folder, you could copy it to Local when your app starts up, then from that point on use the Local file. In other words:

```
public void create() {
    ...
    FileHandle internalFile = Gdx.files.internal(scenarioName);
    internalFile.copyTo(Gdx.files.local(scenarioName);
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks this explains all.

Answer (score 1):

A Libgdx "internal" file is found via the classpath (see the call to `getResourceAsStream` in [FileHandle.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.java#L132)).  On Android these are read-only because they are packaged in the JAR and cannot be modified in-place (the JVM doesn't support that).

I'm a bit surprised that on the desktop version isn't just passing through the call to the local filesystem.  That either means the app is being packaged up in JAR when you're running it (are you running a packaged version, or running a development version from Eclipse?) or there is a ClassLoader somewhere that caches the vaules.

See also [Reloading resources loaded by getResourceAsStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749094/reloading-resources-loaded-by-getresourceasstream)

Comment: Yes PT I bet the application is being packaged. I am running from the eclipse IDE. So it looks like the jar being created and installed before launch. Hence when I modify the file locally on the file system, the changes are not seen until relaunch.